# Package Magento2 extension with custom theme?

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, package, packaging

I have the following structure:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/....**

**app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/mythemename/...**

In my **composer.json** I put something like this:

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that ...",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Iunia ",
      "email": "iunia@test.com"
    }
  ],
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
    "vedor/mythemename": "100.0.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

How do I package it so that it includes the module and the theme? It doesn't like the theme. Using **validate_m2_package.php** I get the following error:

> More than one top-level directory detected, number of directories =
>   3. Top level directory expected to be the module directory.

Do I need to put 
    "type": "metapackage",
in my **composer.json**?

If the answer is yes, how should my composer.json look?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to create 2 composer.json files, so two packages, one for a **magento-module:**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/....**

and the other for a **magento-theme**

**app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/mythemename/...**

> My files look like this:

**app/design/adminhtml/Stannp/backend/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "stannp/backend",
  "description": "Extends the Magento backend theme to add the Stannp logo in the admin panel",
  "require": {
    "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "~100.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-theme",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ]
  }
}
```

and:

**app/code/Stannp/DirectMailing/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "stannp/directmailing",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that connects to Stannp.com API",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    {
    "name": "Stannp Ltd",
    "email": "email1@stannp.com",
    "website": "https://www.stannp.com/"
    },
    {
      "name": "Iunia",
      "email": "iunia@test.com"
    }
  ],
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "stannp/backend": "1.0.0",
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Stannp\\DirectMailing\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

> **Please note**: In my Stannp/backend/composer.json I have  **"magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": "~100.0"** and in my Stannp/DirectMailing/composer.json I put the **version** from the Stannp/backend/composer.json in the *require* section. Also, the name used to require the theme is **stannp/backend**.

Also, when creating a package, you have to do something like this:

```
zip -r stannp_directmailing-1.0.0.zip Block/ Model/ Controller/ Helper/ Model/ Setup/ etc/ composer.json  registration.php view/
```

from inside **app/code/Stannp/DirectMailing/** (!! very important), same process applies for the theme (so from inside of **app/design/adminhtml/Stannp/backend/** folder)

Another important thing to mention is that I added my theme package as a shared package:

[image]

And then added it as a shared package to my extension:

[image]

Hope this helps someone else too. Cheers!

P.S. You can also add the content of the theme as a library (fonts, etc).